# Communication between 2 different networks in Google Cloud with private IP

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have 2 instances: instance1 in network1 and instance2 in network2. I configured the

> tcp port 22

for instance1 with source as

> 0.0.0.0/0

and

> tcp port 1306

for instance2 with source as private IP of instance1.

I logged into the instance1 and tried to telnet the port 1306 of instance2 with the private IP of instance2. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot communicate between the two networks using private/internal IPs. You need to use external/public IPs in order to make them reachable, or site-to-site VPN